# How to get list of image with R.Drawable

Tags: android, image, url, drawable

In order to create a tile management system I have a pack of image in my res/drawable directory. How to load that ressource dynamically ?

like : `F_16.0_0_112.jpg. ("F_"+zoom"+"._"+XCoord+"_"+YCoord".jpg")`

Is there a fonction like getDrawable(String) ?

Comment: you can, but you could put your drawable in a levellistdrawable, or may be in a resource array. (or in the assets folder)

Answer (score 5):

You can get a drawable using its name by:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "id", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get this using reflection (dont forget to import java.lang.reflect.Field)

```
/**
 * For example calling <code>getDrawableId("ic_launcher")</code> will return the same value as <code>R.drawable.ic_launcher;</code> 
 * 
 * @param name the name of the field
 * @return the drawable id
 */
public int getDrawableId(String name) {
    Class<?> c = R.drawable.class;
    Field f = null;
    int id = 0;

    try {
        f = R.drawable.class.getField(name);
        id = f.getInt(null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.i("Reflection", "Missing drawable " + name);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.i("Reflection", "Illegal access to field " + name);
    }

    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, for this use android **assets** folder.

Please see more details [here](http://knowledgefolders.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=2883).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunatly no, you can't load resources by name. The id's are variables in the generated R class. In java, you can't build dynamic variable names.

Comment: of course you can. see http://steven.bitsetters.com/2007/11/27/accessing-android-resources-by-name-at-runtime/