# Checking if image exist till there aren't anymore

Tags: android, image, file, for-loop, try-catch

I'm working on an android project for school. I want it to be very open closed so i thought of a way of checking if there are images till there aren't anymore. But it doesn't work very well.

My code needs to check if the file exist and continue to the next until he can't find anymore.

this is what i have right now:

```
 File file = null;
    try {
        for (int i = 1; 0 < i; i++) {
            String path = "R.drawable.shirt" + i;
            file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Log.d("Kleding", "number: "+i);
                int id = i;
                int prijs = i * 20;
                int gekocht = 0;
                Kleding k = new Kleding(id, prijs, gekocht);
                this.insertKledingInDatabase(k);
            } else {
                Log.d("Kleding", "nothing"+i);
                                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: What is your question? (or problem, maybe?)

Comment: try to get a finite list of  your resources and iterate them, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266774/how-to-get-list-of-image-with-r-drawable

Comment: Checking if there is an image with the name shirt+i(1,2,3). If it is found then it will put in in the Database(ContentProvider) But it doesn't find any image butt there are 5 images. So how can i see if there is an image with there specific name and put the values in the database